# Flutter - Loosing values

Tags: flutter

I have a statefulWidget with params.
I affect a local value with widget value and when i manage the local value, the final widget param changes. I don't understand why

Here's my code

```
class NFTPreviewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const NFTPreviewWidget(
      {super.key,
      this.nftName,
      this.nftDescription,
      this.nftFile,
      this.nftProperties});

  final String? nftName;
  final String? nftDescription;
  final Uint8List? nftFile;
  final List<TokenProperty>? nftProperties;

  @override
  State<NFTPreviewWidget> createState() => _NFTPreviewWidgetState();
}

class _NFTPreviewWidgetState extends State<NFTPreviewWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<TokenProperty>? nftPropertiesDisplayed = widget.nftProperties;
    nftPropertiesDisplayed!.removeWhere((element) =>
        element.name == 'file' ||
        element.name == 'description' ||
        element.name == 'name' ||
        element.name == 'type/mime');
...
```

The final nftProperties property changes in the same time of nftPropertiesDisplayed.

Any idea

Thx

Comment: is there some place where you are trying to put value inside the widget variable? Is the code you shared the entire code for the widget?

Comment: yes. i don't change the value of the widget variable. And it's a final variable

Comment: Then what you are saying doesn't make sense. Where are you using this widget?

Comment: what do mean final widget param changes ? what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a misunderstanding of final lists.

```
 final List<String> myList = ["1", "2", "3"];
```

You can modifiy this list, add and remove items.

```
myList.removeWhere((e) => e == "1");
myList.add("4");
print(myList);
```

The result should be

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

final on this list means you cant assign a new list to it

```
myList = ["0"]; // NOT ALLOWED
```

Comment: You're right. thank you. But why my widget.nftProperties is affected by nftPropertiesDisplayed!.removeWhere ?